# Hashtags linking to identical hashtags using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm working on a sample website for an internship. It's like twitter and I'm trying to add something like hashtags.

I have a working regex and I know how to handle a match to it but I can't figure out how to link tags to identical tags in other posts.

This code may be irrelevant but here it is anyway:

```
@tag = /\B\#\w+/.match(@micropost.content).to_s

if @micropost.content =~ /\B\#\w+/
  @micropost.gsub(/\B\#\w+/, )
end
```

I don't even know if this would work because I have no way to test it, but I would like to replace a match to the regex with a link to all posts containing identical regex matches. The code for a link should probably go after the comma in the body of the if statement, but if anyone knows a better solution I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in my opinion, you need to create a model called `HashTag` or `Trend`. And whenever a user creates a post, you need to create an object of `Trend` remotely through AJAX. So your `Post` model should look like following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trend

end

class Trend < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

end
```

Don't forget to add `trend_id` to your `Post` model. And you need to use [`find_or_create_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) so that when another post uses the same trend, a trend *shouldn't* be created in the database, rather that post should only be associated with the trend.

And since, you also need to show all the posts that belong to a trend, you also need to create `TrendsController`. And each time, user enters a trend, your JS should highlight it, and convert it to the link that upon clicking, takes you to all the posts that belong to that trend.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there a way to do it without AJAX? I don't know it.

Comment: Sure, you can do it without AJAX, but for that case, a trend will only be created or associated when you submit the post. And I'd never prefer doing it without AJAX.